# 'wrong-type-argument stringp nil' Error With org-babel-load-file Function

Tags: org-mode, debugging

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://endlessparentheses.com/init-org-Without-org-mode.html) to implement my `init.el` file in org mode. I therefore cleaned out my `init.el` file and added this only:

```
(require 'org)
(org-babel-load-file
 (expand-file-name "emacs-init.org"
                   user-emacs-directory))
```

When I do I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  expand-file-name(nil)
  load-file(nil)
  org-babel-load-file("/home/tom/.emacs.d/emacs-init.org")
  mapc(org-babel-load-file ("/home/tom/.emacs.d/emacs-init.org"))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/tom/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1065
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/tom/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/tom/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/tom/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  ...
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

It seems that the `expand-file-name` function is working, but for some reason `nil` is being passed to the `load-file` function. Is that a proper reading of this stack trace? And if so, then why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after using Drew's debugging steps I learned that `org-babel-load-file` basically does the following:

1. Load your `emacs-init.org` file in org-mode.
2. Strip out all of the emacs-lisp code blocks that contain your emacs config.
3. Put those emacs-lisp code blocks into a file called `emacs-init.el`.
4. It then executes the code in that file.

My issue was that my `emacs-init.org` file didn't yet contain any emacs-lisp code blocks so it couldn't create the `emacs-init.el` file, which is why `nil` is being passed to `load-file`.

So here's what I'm doing instead that is working much better.

1. I added the code snippet in my question to the top of my existing `init.el` file.
2. I then created an `emacs-init.org` file in the `.emacs.d` dir.
3. I then moved a couple lines of config from `init.el` to `emacs-init.org`.
4. I then start a second emacs process to test everything.

My plan is to move everything in chunks like this.

Answer (score 5):

Load the source file that defines org-babel-load-file (`*.el`, not `*.elc`). Then `M-x debug-on-entry org-babel-load-file`. Use `d` to step through the execution, to see why, given the argument `"/home/tom/.emacs.d/emacs-init.org"`, it ends up trying to load `nil` and not a file name.  You can use `c` to skip through any steps you are not interested in digging into.

See the Elisp manual, node [Function Debugging](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Debugging.html) (and its parent node, [Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugger.html)).

Comment: This is really fantastic advice and I used this debugging process to solve the problem. Thanks again Drew! I didn't accept it as the answer though because there's a much more direct route to solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell your "emacs-init.org" which language is it.

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC LANGUAGE NAME
.
.
.
#+END_SRC
```

Example for emacs-lisp

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
#+END_SRC
```